# System.Diagnostic.Tracing.EventListener for existing ETW Providers

Tags: .net, f#, etw, perfview

I am confused how to create an `EventListener` for an existing system ETW Provider. The `EnableEvents` method expects to be passed in a `EventSource` instance. Do I need to create that by hand? Is there a way to generate that `EventSource` class?

I can find out details out a provider doing either:

```bsh
logman query providers Microsoft-Windows-WinHttp
wevtutil get-publisher Microsoft-Windows-WinHttp
```

I can even generate the `instrumentationManifest` xml with:

```bsh
.\PerfView.exe /nogui userCommand DumpRegisteredManifest Microsoft-Windows-WinHttp
```

```ml
open System.Diagnostics.Tracing

let printfn format = Printf.ksprintf System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine format

[<EventSource(Name="Microsoft-Windows-NDIS-PacketCapture", Guid="2ed6006e-4729-4609-b423-3ee7bcd678ef")>]
type NdisPacketCaptureEventSource() =
    inherit EventSource()

let Ethernet = LanguagePrimitives.EnumOfValue<int64, EventKeywords>(0x1L)
let WirelessWAN = LanguagePrimitives.EnumOfValue<int64, EventKeywords>(0x200L)

let Api = LanguagePrimitives.EnumOfValue<int64, EventKeywords>(0x1L)
let Send = LanguagePrimitives.EnumOfValue<int64, EventKeywords>(0x100000000L)

[<EventSource(Name="Microsoft-Windows-WinHttp", Guid="7d44233d-3055-4b9c-ba64-0d47ca40a232")>]
type WinHttpEventSource() =
    inherit EventSource()

type MyEventListener() =
    inherit EventListener()

    override x.OnEventSourceCreated source =
        printfn "OnEventSourceCreated %A" source
        base.OnEventSourceCreated source

    override x.OnEventWritten args =
        printfn "OnEventWritten %A" args
        base.OnEventWritten args

[<EntryPoint>]
let main argv = 
    use listener = new MyEventListener()

//    use ndis = new NdisPacketCaptureEventSource()
//    printfn "Name: %s, Guid: %A" ndis.Name ndis.Guid
//    listener.EnableEvents(ndis, EventLevel.Verbose, EventKeywords.All)
//    listener.EnableEvents(ndis, EventLevel.Verbose, Ethernet)
//    listener.EnableEvents(ndis, EventLevel.Verbose, WirelessWAN)

    use winHttp = new WinHttpEventSource()
//    listener.EnableEvents(winHttp, EventLevel.Verbose, EventKeywords.All)
    listener.EnableEvents(winHttp, EventLevel.Verbose, Send)

//    for i in 0 .. 5 do
//    System.Console.ReadKey() |> ignore
    while true do
        System.Threading.Thread.Sleep 100
    0
```

[image: Output]

I haven't been able to trigger `OnEventWritten` and I don't know why. Any ideas?

#### Update on 2015-12-02

I was able to get `EventSource` events logging using SemanticLogging. The [details are here](https://github.com/mspnp/semantic-logging/issues/59#issuecomment-161494036). It is using [Microsoft.Diagnostics.Tracing.TraceEvent](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.Diagnostics.Tracing.TraceEvent/). Using it appears like it may be the solution.

Answer (score 3):

I didn't quite understand what I was asking. I wanted to log events from ETL. On Vance Morrison's Weblog, [he explains](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/archive/blogs/vancem/rich-payload-data-in-eventsource-v4-6) `EventSource keeps these track of these data item names and types so that processors (either EventListeners or ETW)`. The EventListener I was trying to use was for events in the same process. `TraceEvent` can be used for getting the events from another process. The [samples](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.Diagnostics.Tracing.TraceEvent.Samples/) he made available are great and I used them to create this.

```ml
open System

// https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.Diagnostics.Tracing.TraceEvent/
open Microsoft.Diagnostics.Tracing
open Microsoft.Diagnostics.Tracing.Session

// toggle this on for VS Output window or off for Console window
let printfn format = Printf.ksprintf System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine format

[<EntryPoint>]
let main argv = 
    
    if not (TraceEventSession.IsElevated().GetValueOrDefault()) then
        printfn "you must run as admin"
        1

    else 
        let name = "Microsoft-AdoNet-SystemData"
        let guid = TraceEventProviders.GetProviderGuidByName name
        printfn "name: %s, guid: %A" name guid
        use sn = new TraceEventSession("MySession")
        sn.Source.add_AllEvents (fun evt -> printfn "event: %A" evt)
        sn.EnableProvider(name, TraceEventLevel.Verbose) |> ignore
        Console.CancelKeyPress.Add (fun args -> args.Cancel <- true; sn.Dispose())
        sn.Source.Process() |> ignore
        0
```

[image]